# Error: Network Error with React, Express, Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to run a website on an AWS EC2 instance using React, Express and Axios.

The problem: I'm unable to make `axios` calls to the Express back-end running on the same instance. The code works fine on my local machine, but on the EC2 instance I get `Error: Network Error`. The server runs on port 5000 and the client runs on port 3000. I'm able to access the website from the outside using the URL, and am able to make `GET` requests to the back-end directly using Postman.

**Home.js** (frontend)

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Home() {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://172.31.20.10:5000/`)
            .then(
                result => {
                    setText(result.data);
                },
                err => {
                    alert(err);
                    setText('An error has occurred');
                }
            );
    });

    return (
        <h1>{ text }</h1>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**App.js** (frontend)

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Home from './Home';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Home />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js** (backend)

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express()
const port = 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

`172.31.20.10` is the private IP of the EC2 instance. I've tried using `localhost` instead of the IP, `https://` instead of `http://`, not use `http(s)` at all, leaving the `http` and IP/localhost out entirely, etc etc. None have worked so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried your posted code on local computer? In general, Network Error points to a problem with infrastructure. If so, this question is off topic for [so]

Comment: please provide the whole error network message

Answer (score 0):

To answer the comments: The code did work on my own computer, and the whole network error was a CORS error ("CORS request did not go through" or some such).

I'm still not exactly sure what went wrong, but I "solved" it by hosting the client and server on two different instances. Not sure how or why it works, but it did...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).